# Livewire submit form creates duplicate records in database

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-livewire

I have a form in modal and I'm using Livewire, what's really happens is when I submit the form everything works correctly but it just creates duplicate records!
The first time creates 2 duplicates, the second time creates 3 and more and more.
I don't know how to fix this!
I'd be appreciated for your help.

this is my livewire view file :

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="createProfessionModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdrop" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!--begin::Container-->
                <div class="card card-custom card-shadowless rounded-top-0">
                    <!--begin::Body-->
                    <div class="card-body p-0">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center py-8">
                            <!--begin::Wizard Form-->
                            <form class="form fv-plugins-bootstrap fv-plugins-framework" id="createProfessionForm" method="post" wire:submit.prevent="store">
                                <div class="justify-content-center">
                                    <!--begin::Wizard-->
                                    <div class="my-5 step">
                                        <h5 class="text-dark font-weight-bold mb-10">ایحاد حرفه جدید</h5>
                                        <!--begin::Group-->
                                        <div class="form-group row fv-plugins-icon-container">
                                            <label class="col-form-label" for="profession_title">عنوان حرفه</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
                                                <input id="profession_title" class="form-control form-control-solid form-control-lg" wire:model.defer="title" name="title" type="text">
                                                <div class="fv-plugins-message-container"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--end::Group-->
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bolder px-9 py-4" >ایجاد</button>
                                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-outline-info font-weight-bolder px-9 py-4" >بستن</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--end::Wizard-->
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end::Wizard Form-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

script:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  $('#createProfessionForm').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let professionValue = $('#profession_title').val();

      @this.set('title', professionValue, true);
      @this.store();
  })
})
```

this is my component

```php
    public string $title;

    public function store()
    {
        try {
            $profession = new Profession();
            $profession->name = $this->title;
            $profession->save();
            session()->flash('success', 'عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد.');
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            session()->flash('error', __($exception->getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: jQuery will not work then.

Comment: Could it be that your DOM loaded event triggers each time Livewire refreshes? Because that would mean you're re-binding the submit function, therefore submitting one time more each time you submit. Try `console.log('loaded')` and check the console to see if the event triggers multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions), you don't need to bind the event in Javascript like you're doing here.
[image: your script]

Because if you do that, the request is firing twice. You can check for the same in the network as well.